# Open IE via C# -> mailto fails

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, outlook, mailto, process.start

I found some strange behavior in ie started by `Process.Start()` (.Net Framework)
To reproduce this just follow following steps.

**Required:**

- C# IDE+compiler
- outlook (in my situation: outlook 2010 - other versions should be the same problem but not tested)
- ie9 (ie8 or 10 should be "good" too)
- ie must be the default browser (u can switch back later ;-) )
- outlook must be related to mailto: links

**Steps (success):**

- close all IE and Outlook instances
- open IE (32bit)
- open URL: `mailto:foo@example.com`

***Result:*** Outlook starts

**Steps (fail)**

- close all IE and Outlook instances
- compile this code-fragment
  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.example.org");`
- execute the code
  (IE should start showing the example page)
- Now type or copy `mailto:foo@example.com` to your url-bar

***Result:*** Cannot start Microsoft Outlook (or something like that) - WTF?

**What I checked already:**

IE starts with same

- parameter
- working directory
- user
- architecture (32bit)

what am i doing wrong?
it'd be nice if there are some more ideas out there what i can check, test, look for.

Comment: Interesting. Same thing happens to me with the same versions of IE and Outlook (can't try other versions) on Win7-64 (but using 32-bit IE). Get the message:
Another version of Outlook is currently running.  Close it and try again.

Comment: Either way works for me - what happens if you specify the program to start instead of just using the default browser? `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "http://www.example.org");` Is the behavior the same?

Comment: It's something to do with protected mode - if you turn off protected mode for the Internet zone (*not recommended!*), the link will work.

Comment: @Richard but why are there different protected mode settings for starting via Start-menue and by csharp?

Comment: @SliverNinja same result wenn starting explicit ie by using your code-fragment. Which Outlook, Windows and IE Version did you try?

Comment: @wischi Worked for me on Outlook 2007, Win7-64, IE8

Comment: @SliverNinja: Doesn't work for me: Win7x64, IE9, Outlook 2010. Using [IELaunchURL](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/09/using-ielaunchurl-in-c-to-launch-a-protected-mode-internet-explorer-7-window/) also fails. Launching from an elevated process works. Launching IE9x64 works.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the behaviour. In my case I have an Outlook Addin causing the problem.

```
---------------------------
MS Outlook Extension
---------------------------
The <Outlook Addin Name> MS Outlook Extension can't be loaded because Outlook is currently in use by another application. Please try again later.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Once I removed this Addin it now works.

Something also that may be of help is this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C

Impersonating another user may help if your problem is not an Addin like mine was.

Comment: in my situation there messagebox does not show any extensionnames with troubles. Which Addin caused the problem in your situation?

Comment: I was using third party addin. Autotask. I would try disabling all and see what you get. It could be any one of them.